# Select all groups of elements placed immediately after another using xpath expression

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html

```
<div class="A"> A </div>
<div class="B"> 1 </div>
<div class="B"> 2 </div>
<div class="B"> 3 </div>
<div class="A"> A </div>
<div class="B"> 4 </div>
<div class="B"> 5 </div>
<div class="A"> A </div>
<div class="B"> 6 </div>
```

and I want to extract all div elements immediately placed after div element with class="A", using an xpath expression.

I've tried to create an expression that uses + operator without success:

```
//div[@class='A']+div[@class='B']
```

I expect the output divided in groups. For example, the first group should be:

```
<div class="B"> 1 </div>
<div class="B"> 2 </div>
<div class="B"> 3 </div>
```

the second

```
<div class="B"> 4 </div>
<div class="B"> 5 </div>
```

and the last one

```
<div class="B"> 6 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution.

You have to:

1. get the number of occurences of  elements
2. for each index i, evaluate the xpath expression

   > //div[not(@class="A") and
   >   count(preceding-sibling::div[@class="A"])=(i+1)]